# Encrypt the Sqlite Database file using XUL and Javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, security, encryption, xul

I am working on the XUL based application which uses a SQLite database for storage.
I am using javascript API which interacts with XUL and SQLite and I can perform any command (like insert update delete) using this JavaScript API.

Now the problem is that I have downloaded a third party tool for SQLite editing. I realize that, using this editor, anyone can modify the database tables. So, I want to make a encrypted or secure SQLite file.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Sync API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Firefox_Sync/JavaScript_Client_API) which has an encrypted [storage format](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Services/Sync/Developer/StorageFormat) as in the following add-ons:

- [XMarks Sync](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xmarks-sync/)
- [Stylish Sync](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylishsync/)

[McCoy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/McCoy) may also be an option.